# Move elements back and forth depending on screen width with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The point of this is to move elements into another HTML container on screen resizing. So when it hits a targeted width, it moves in to the new container then, returns if it's not the target width on resize. Problem is, I can get it to work under the width but can't put them back when resizing the screen:

HTML:

```
<div id="target">
  <!-- move-me goes in here -->
</div>

<div id="original">
  <div class="move-me">
    <p>Stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="move-me">
    <p>Stuff</p>
  </div>
  <div class="move-me">
    <p>Stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function moveDetails() {
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let target = document.getElementById("target");
    let origin = document.getElementById("original");
    let moveMe = document.querySelectorAll(".move-me");
    if(screenWidth <= 1100) {
        moveMe.forEach(m => {
            target.innerHTML += m.innerHTML;
            m.innerHTML = "";
        });
    } 
}
moveDetails();
```

I tried grabbing the "original" id then reversing it with an else, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated, vanilla JS if possible.

**Update #1: Solution!**

After even more digging (check out [this link](https://gomakethings.com/breakpoint-conditional-javascript-in-vanilla-js/) for a better explanation). This works on both whichever breakpoint you set, loads properly on each device and changing parent container when resizing. Still need to implement the dry version.

JS:

```
function moveDetails() {
    /*
    Call your targets, both inner width and client width finally, set break point
    */
    let target = document.getElementById("target"),
            origin = document.getElementById("original"),
            moveMe = document.querySelectorAll(".move-me"),
            breakPoint = 1100,
            viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    /*
    This is for anything below the breakpoint on refersh so the changes immediately show.
    We'll use the method "appendChild()" throughout on the parent elements.
    */      
    if (viewportWidth < breakPoint) {
        moveMe.forEach(m => {
            target.appendChild(m);
        });
    }
    /*
    addEventListener of 'resize' so it will add/remove elements with the
    given class name to the targeted ids/parents
    */
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (viewportWidth < breakPoint) {
            moveMe.forEach(m => {
                target.appendChild(m);
            });
        } else {
            moveMe.forEach(m => {
                origin.appendChild(m);
            });
        }
    });
}
moveDetails();
```

To also note, this is great for grabbing specific class named elements. Most methods I came across would select EVERY child element. So, if you need to grab something specific, hopefully this would help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are opting to do this with JS rather than CSS media queries?  The latter would seem to be the more idiomatic and performant approach, but I appreciate sometimes there are unique cases.

Comment: The layout is pretty complex and the target elements have to move to different containers because of this. It's easy to display:none then display: block, hiding elements, adding more markup, etc. But these elements are being generated by PHP, so I'm trying a "code once" approach.

Comment: Glad you were able to come up w/ a solution to your own problem.  You might consider posting it as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Does it work as expected inside of a `resize` event handler?

```
  document.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
        let target = document.getElementById("target");
        let origin = document.getElementById("original");
        let moveMe = document.querySelectorAll(".move-me");
        if(screenWidth <= 1100) {
            moveMe.forEach(m => {
                target.innerHTML += m.innerHTML;
                m.innerHTML = "";
            });
       } 
  });
```

Comment: Questions are usually best in comments, not answers.

Comment: Point taken, I just took my question as also a possible solution to the problem he was experiencing, and knew my code example wouldn't fit well in a comment.

Comment: Quite close however this works only one way and with window.addEventListener, thanks. Will mess around with this one to see if a solution pops up

Comment: I'm thinking probably this + adding the else logic would do the trick, but good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an else statement, as at the moment, you are only doing something when the width is less than or equal to 1100.

Have also updated your variables to use const rather than let, as they are not being reassigned.

```
function moveDetails() {
    const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    const target = document.getElementById("target");
    const origin = document.getElementById("original");
    const moveMe = document.querySelectorAll(".move-me");
    if(screenWidth <= 1100) {
        moveMe.forEach(m => {
            target.innerHTML += m.innerHTML;
            m.innerHTML = "";
        });
    } else { // your code here }
}
moveDetails();
```

Comment: I've already tried an else statement to add it back into the original container, but it duplicates the move elements and only works when the page is refreshed. Although when a phone or desktop user visits the page, they can see the elements where they need to be but ideally, would like to work whilst being resized.

Comment: Correction: I've done else statement originally, very poorly. Please check the main post for the updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Update #1: Solution!**

After even more digging (check out [this link](https://gomakethings.com/breakpoint-conditional-javascript-in-vanilla-js/) for a better explanation). This works on both whichever breakpoint you set, loads properly on each device and changing parent container when resizing. Still need to implement the dry version.

JS:

```
function moveDetails() {
    /*
    Call your targets, both inner width and client width finally, set break point
    */
    let target = document.getElementById("target"),
            origin = document.getElementById("original"),
            moveMe = document.querySelectorAll(".move-me"),
            breakPoint = 1100,
            viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    /*
    This is for anything below the breakpoint on refersh so the changes immediately show.
    We'll use the method "appendChild()" throughout on the parent elements.
    */      
    if (viewportWidth < breakPoint) {
        moveMe.forEach(m => {
            target.appendChild(m);
        });
    }
    /*
    addEventListener of 'resize' so it will add/remove elements with the
    given class name to the targeted ids/parents
    */
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        let viewportWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        if (viewportWidth < breakPoint) {
            moveMe.forEach(m => {
                target.appendChild(m);
            });
        } else {
            moveMe.forEach(m => {
                origin.appendChild(m);
            });
        }
    });
}
moveDetails();
```

To also note, this is great for grabbing specific class named elements. Most methods I came across would select EVERY child element. So, if you need to grab something specific, hopefully this would help.